# Why my clojure repl formatting is broken?

Tags: clojure

I am new to Clojure, and I am usually using it from (Spac)emacs, where the repl formats fine. However, when I try to use the repl within a gnome-terminal, then the formatting is broken, i.e. after 'sending' some code, the line of code gets 'reformatted' as shown in the screencast below:
[image]

Anybody has some idea what is going on here? The terminal is just a basic 'gnome-terminal' on Fedora.

B.t.w. the same screencast is used for reporting [an issue with criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium/issues/57) about the `bench` example hanging.

Comment: `clj` by default tries to run `rlwrap ... clojure`; do you have `rlwrap` installed? Do you see the same problem when you just run `clojure`? Can we assume, that you don't see problems like that with other CLI tools?

Comment: Everything is exactly as you asked/assumed. Do you have any advice for a fix? (maybe provide it as an answer so that I can accept it) Although it does not have high priority at all because usually I am using the 'cider' repl in Emacs. Anyway, thanks a lot for the useful answer.

Comment: Have you tried without `rlwrap` (run `clojure` instead of `clj`)?

Comment: Ah yes, I meant that when I meant 'everything' (all 3 points) was exactly like you assumed, which indeed was not phrased very clearly. So indeed the repl from the `clojure` command does not show the issue. But then it also does not 'provide' the `rlwrap` functionality. So what I meant to ask was if you have some advice for a fix/workaround for the 'formatting' issue while using `clj` with `rlwrap`. But again, the fix is not very important for me because I typically use the repl in Emacs. Just, if you happen to have some idea, it might be handy to include it here.

Comment: I have the same problem. Using `clojure` does work. I do have rlwrap (0.45) installed.

Comment: As an alternative you could try out
https://github.com/bhauman/rebel-readline#clojure-tools - has
everything, that rlwrap has, but more and better.

Comment: That looks great! I am on a different PC now (without clojure tools), but I will check it out further ASAP. You could summarize these comments in an official answer, so I could accept it (it is only 2 to 3 lines). Or otherwise (if you prefer) I could do it also, but then, of course, I would 'steal' your 'reputation' :) The choice is up to you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: this is not a solution to the problem, but it shows,
where the problem lies and what are workarounds.

TL;DR: call `clojure` (which does not use `rlwrap`¹; use
[Rebel-Readline](https://github.com/bhauman/rebel-readline#clojure-tools)
instead, for more features

`clj` calls `clojure`, but checks, if `rlwrap` is installed and uses
that to call `clojure` with some settings, that are suitable for a Lisp.

`rlwrap` is a great tool, to get `readline` capabilities with
interactive CLI tools, that don't have it (e.g. emacs/vi-mode, history,
"hippy" completion).  But in this case it is the culprit to smash up the
REPL.  What's underlying problem is not clear, but in cases like this
the options usually are: buggy software (the terminal, `rlwrap`, or the
way Clojure interacts with the terminal), wrong/buggy `TERM` settings or
term-capabilities.

That said, `rlwrap` might be the "just good enough" option here
anyway.  First of all Clojure developers tend to use the REPL via the
editor anyway.  Second there is a far superior option to get what
`rlwrap` brings to the table:
[Rebel-Readline](https://github.com/bhauman/rebel-readline#clojure-tools)

Beside emacs/vi-modes and history it brings (and probably more):

- syntax highlighting for both input and output (with pretty-printing)
- multi-line edit in the REPL
- proper auto-completion
- showing the doc-string of the function under the cursor

---

¹) From: https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap

> rlwrap is a 'readline wrapper', a small utility that uses the GNU Readline library to allow the editing of keyboard input for any command.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `rlwrap` bug that has been fixed upstream (but, as of now, is still open in [several](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1029664) [distributions](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=269416)) . In a nutshell, either:

- use a recent `rlwrap` (0.46-1 or newer),
- or avoid the very newest `readline` (8.2 or newer),
- or put `set enable-bracketed-paste off` in your `inputrc`

See this [bug report on Github](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/168) (or [this summary](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/108#issuecomment-1400732430) of the history of this issue)

Hans Lub (`rlwrap` maintainer)

Comment: Thanks, for this useful info. In the meantime, the rlwrap library on Fedora (what I am using) has been updated to version 0.46.1, and indeed the issue has been fixed (thanks a lot for that also ;).